# hibernate dynamic table name

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

How to specify a table name that comes dynamically in the form of annotation for  hibernate domain object ? OR is there any way to set the table name dynamically for a hibernate domain object without annotating it ?

Iam using Hibernate annotations @Entity and @Table. I want to set the table name dynamically to @Table. Is it possible?

In my schema I have different table names with same structure, with thousands of records in it. I don't want to write domain class for all these tables.
Thank you

Comment: do u want to add dynamic table name without @Entity  like that?

Answer (score -3):

Try this `@Table(name="tab_name")`

Comment: Is it dynamic, can you change table at runtime

Comment: Then do you think your answer is relevant to what is being asked - `I want to set the table name dynamically to @Table. Is it possible?`

Comment: you can use @SecondaryTable for saving in two tables but not at runtime.

Comment: Sorry When I saw that question its like how to change the table name thats why i have posted this.

Comment: My question is : I want to set table name at runtime. My requirement is : I will get table name from another table which is at runtime. I want this table name set to @Table.